# Spring Boot, Swagger and Authorisation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

I have a Spring Boot API that uses Springdoc (Swagger).  The API has security with "apiKey" and "code" fields being passed in the header.  I am having difficulty configuring Swagger correctly to enable the Authentication function in the Swagger UI.  This is the configuration:

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI alartaCoreAdtAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("BASIC"))
            .components(
               new Components()
                   .addSecuritySchemes("BASIC",
                       new SecurityScheme()
                           .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                           .scheme("basic")
                           .name("code")
                                            
                   )
            )               

              .info(new Info().title(config.getApiTitle())
              .description(config.getApiDescription())
              .version(config.getApiVersion())
              .license(new 
             License().name(config.getApiLicenseTitle()).url(config.getApiLicenseUrl())))
);
  }
```

I know this is incorrect, but are unsure how to configure it.

Any assistance appreciated.

Attempts at solution:
from @indybee recommendation:

```
@Bean
    public OpenAPI alartaCoreAdtAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("BASIC"))
                  
                .components( new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes("apiKey", securityScheme("apiKey"))
                        .addSecuritySchemes("code", securityScheme("code"))
                        )

                  .info(new Info().title(config.getApiTitle())
                  .description(config.getApiDescription())
                  .version(config.getApiVersion())
                  .license(new License().name(config.getApiLicenseTitle()).url(config.getApiLicenseUrl())))
                  );
      } 
    
    private SecurityScheme securityScheme(String name) {
        return new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme()
            .type(io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
            .in(io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
            .name(name);
    }
```

This is where I get to (unfortunately, it still doesn't authorize when I test an endpoint)

[image]

Finally, this appears to work (using guidance from @indybee):

addSecurityItem()

```
        .components( new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes("apiKey", securityScheme("apiKey"))
                .addSecuritySchemes("code", securityScheme("code"))
                )
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("apiKey").addList("code"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass 2 custom headers of "apiKey" and "code" with every request

add this method:

```
private SecurityScheme securityScheme(String name) {
    return new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme()
        .type(io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
        .in(io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
        .name(name);
}
```

and replace your .components() block with following

```
.components(new Components()
        .addSecuritySchemes("apiKey", securityScheme("apiKey"))
        .addSecuritySchemes("code", securityScheme("code"))
    )
```

[image: Authorize dialog]

[image: curl command]

Comment: thank you for this @indybee.  I have modified the code, however the authorise dialog only displays a single field ("code") in this case

Comment: Possibly browser cache - cleared and it now displays two fields.  Regardless Swagger dosen't appear to add them into the curl call

Comment: Perhaps I use different version and has difference. What version of springdoc you use?

Comment: also in Authorize dialog, after you enter apiKey and code, you clicked "Authorize" button before close dialog?  and then try api call after?

Comment: Using version 1.6.4.  Yes, it presents as two sections; two fields and two "Authorize" buttons.  I will modify my question and add an image

Comment: It do not seem to be because of version different. I tried with 1.6.2 and 1.6.4.  I added my images for comparison.  Only other thing maybe if you have defined groups then will require different configuration within the groups

Comment: Thank you for your help - I finally made some progress and have added to the question.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part was different in your original post then what I used for testing and missed including that part in answer.  I am glad you got it working.